# I can't download Firefox in Ubuntu arm server 22.04.2 Lts version

Tags: 22.04, firefox, downloads

While downloading Firefox in Ubuntu 22.04 Lts version I got this message,"your system is unable to reach snap store "
it also gave 3 options
1.retry
2.abort
3.skip

Comment: Try switching to the non-snap version https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401

Answer (score 0):

Check that your internet connection is working properly: Try a test ping.

Then 'Retry'.